# console.log specifc key in object from vaible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a object that is in an array:

```
console.log(myBox[0]);
// newBox { box_id=1,  color="red"}
```

I am trying to console.log just the color. I tried this:

```
console.log(myBox[0,1]);
```

But it is undefined, what is the proper syntax to display "red"

Comment: What do you need help with

Comment: @CodeiSir answer worked perfect. thanks!

Comment: 8 more min and it will let me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This: `console.log(myBox[0].color);`

You can access the property of the object by pointing to its name